# jQuery Traversing closest() and find()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write function which will be counting checked checkboxes and put quantity in span element.

I tried to get to closest span in div with class btnTest but it doesn't work but if I go to this class directly it works fine. Hope anyone can help me. Thank you in advance for support.

Here is a jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //function get_filter borrowed from https://www.webslesson.info/2018/05/angularjs-php-mysql-crud.html

  function get_filter(class_name)
  {
      var filter = [];
      $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function(){
          filter.push($(this).val());
      });
      return filter;
  }

  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {

  let checkClass = $(this).attr('class');
  let closestSpan = $(this).closest('.btnTest').find('span'); //it doesn't work
  //let closestSpan = $('.btnTest span'); //this one work fine
  let checkboxCount = get_filter(checkClass).length;

if(checkboxCount > 0) {
$(closestSpan).html(' ('+ checkboxCount +')');
} else {
$(closestSpan).html('');
}
  });

});
```

And here is a html:

```
  <div class="btnTest">Owner<span></span><i class="arrow down"></i></div>
  <div class="selectOptions">
  <ol>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="owner" value="1">Owner1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="owner" value="2">Owner2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="owner" value="3">Owner3</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="owner" value="4">Owner4</label></li>
  </ol>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Because `.btnTest` is not a direct ancestor of the `input` tags.

Comment: Review [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) - it's "closest parent" not "nearest on the page"

Comment: off topic: your `get_filter` method is superfluous - replace `get_filter(checkClass).length` with `$(".owner:checked").length`

Comment: You probably want `$(this).closest(".selectOptions").prev()` or wrap both in an outer wrapper and go up to that then back down to `.btnTest`

Comment: It is amazing few minutes and problem solved. Below working code. Thank you very much.

  let closestSpan = $(this).closest('.selectOptions').prev().find('span');